# jQuery change selection and trigger change callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a dialog with multiple tabs, the first tab has a list ("SELECT") when a selection is made from the list the number of tabs may change as a result of the callback attached to the list.

In my source I the list callback is attached with:

```
    $("#listID").bind("change", function() {
       //Do something
    });
```

In code I want to change the list selection and trigger calling of the change callback.  I've tried:

```
    $("#listID").val(3);  //3 is one of the valid option values
```

This didn't result in the change callback being called so I added:

```
    $("#listID").change();
```

After the setting of the value, this doesn't work either, if I look at the list the high light has not moved.

I've searched online and what I've done should work but it doesn't.  What haven't I done?

Here is the HTML:

```
    <select id="listID" size="11">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: what is `listID`? Is it a `Select` tag? As well check if the id `listID` is not used anywhere else as `ids` are unique.

Comment: @randomSoul, the SELECT tag is defined with the id attribute set to listID.  Isn't that clear by the jQuery # prefix ?

Comment: Yes I know it's a `id`. my question was ` is it on `select` tag? I can't reproduce your issue. Pleas reproduce your issue, so that we can help you.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit and include the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work fine doing `$("#listID").val(3).change()`

Note that `bind()` is deprecated and you should use `on()`

```js
$("#listID").on("change", function() {
  console.log(`Changed value to ${this.value}`)
});

$("#listID").val(3).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="listID">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

If it's not working there is something missing in question as to why

Comment: It doesn't work, could it be something to do with the tabs?  The selection doesn't change and the callback is not called, yet if I manually change the selection the call back is called.

Comment: Are there any plugins involved? Are you changing the value *before* the event listener is added? Does the element exist at run time?

Comment: @SPlatten: I think you're going to have add the HTML of some of your 'tabs' to show what you're doing with them so that we can accurately reproduce your problem.

Comment: It all works now, my problem was no more than a typo in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#listID").val(2).trigger('change'); //to trigger the change event with value 2
```

Comment: Thank you, but still the callback isn't being called.

Comment: can u include your html content in the question

Comment: `change()` with no parameters is same as `trigger('change')`. Should also provide an explanation as to why this would help OP's problem

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.